# css - width fit to content

Tags: html, css, slider

I built a site with the following structure:

```
body
 div pos: absolute; width: 3200px
  div pos: static; width: fit-content <- 20 - 30 pcs in a row
   div pos: relative; width: 100%
    div pos: absolute; width 30%
```

The first div is actually a long slider, the width is manually set to fit the contents.
But I want the width to be set automatically. 
The fit-content option results in no width at all.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Post sample code here.

Comment: `display:inline` or `inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Work with percentages like you do with the other divs. Set it to 100% instead of 3200px